# How To Implement Custom Dropdown in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to get the result as shown below. I have managed to get the rest working except the dropdown part, I have the Icon but the dropdown part, I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried using Popup Menu and Dropdown Menu. None of them works as I needed to. Any pointers anyone can give on this design? Thanks.

[image: Dropdown Mock]

Comment: What do you mean by the ```icon```? are you referring to the checkbox on the dropdownmenu items?

Comment: I think PopupButton suits better than dropdown button for you.

Comment: @Reign The downarrow icon. So the row will have `Date range: <Selected Value if exists> <DownArrowIcon> <Close Icon>

Comment: @Ranjit I tried the Popup Button but it doesn't detect Checkbox, instead it is only detecting the whole row.